# Does Flash only render the on-screen part of a movieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3

A client has asked me to use an enormous 4000 x 4000 px movieClip (or larger – not sure what the size limit is) containing shape data for pan/scroll type functionality. This has been suggested as an alternative to writing a tiling engine.

I am concerned that Flash will have to render this entire area and use too much memory. I haven't kept up with the changes to the innards of Flash. Can anyone confirm if Flash has an "all or nothing" render policy for a specific movieClip or is it able to identify what will be on-screen?

Alternately, is there an open source tiling engine with a simple API? I don't want to have to deal with the complexity of a game engine just for the tiling functionality.

The application is a map presentation tool

**Update:**

I should have been more explicit: I was asking about how Flash renders **vector data** – if a movieClip of vector data is larger than the stage does Flash render only the visible parts?

[image]

Comment: I don't know the details of how Flash optimizes its rendering process, but a 4000x4000 isn't that humungous for Flash to handle, if you cache it as a bitmap. It will certainly have some overhead on the renderer, but it won't be the same as trying to render a full 4000x4000 viewport. Also, `scrollRect` is a good way to optimize. Adobe Scout might give you some better insight.

Comment: In theory yes the overextending graphic parts are not displayed and should not impact rendering and CPU speed. In practice we often see those hidden parts having an impact especially when moving the graphic.

Answer (score 0):

> is there an open source tiling engine with a simple API? I don't want to have to deal with the complexity of a game engine just for the tiling functionality.

I think you are overcomplicating this if you ask for an *engine* if there's only one source image.

Create a `Rectangle` with the desired size of the portion you want to see, which would be the screen size.

```
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle (/* size and position go here*/);
```

Add a `Bitmap` and `BitmapData` which serve as View and Model (so to speak), with the same size as the rectangle:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width, rect.height);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

Then just `copyPixels()` the desired rectangle from the source into your `bitmapData`.

```
bitmapData.copyPixels(sourceImage, rect, new Point());
```

To view a different area of the image, modify the `Rectangle` object and copy again.

The above code is just to illustrate and probably doesn't even compile, but it shows that there isn't much to it and you should be able to get the desired functionality within a few liens of code.

The restrictions on the size are [according to the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) as follows:

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the maximum size for a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels in width or height, and the total number of pixels cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the limitation is 2,880 pixels in height and 2,880 in width.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the idea is to be able to pan/zoom a map which could be large – larger than 4000 x 4000 – a sort of "Google Maps Lite" - so being able to tile images would be more efficient/scalable. Screen size is 1024 x 786 – so I can get a few screens of map using one large bitmap but clients always want more. . . right? This is offline in AIR so no download size issue.

Comment: Bitmap blitting is fine as long as you don't use it on mobile device (in which this process is too slow to be used)